# (Excel) change time from minutes to decimals

Tags: excel, datetime

I have times formatted like `4.45` (meaning 4 hours 45 mins) how can I format it to `4.75` (change from minutes to 1/100 of hour) ?

Comment: Multiply .45 by 100 and divide through 60. :)

Comment: Is there any faster way? I have many of these hours.minutes to change to decimals and this doesn't sound fast method, defeating its purpose tbh fam.

Comment: Some method that would use cell reference might be handy, so that i could just copy+paste it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to go from 9.30 (9 hours and 30 mins) to 9.5 (9.5 hours) use this fucntion

```
=(A1-TRUNC(A1,0))/0.6+TRUNC(A1)
```

to reverse that use this function

```
=(A1-TRUNC(A1,0))*0.6+TRUNC(A1)
```

Comment: I had to change `,` to `;` at (A1,0)) but after that this works, thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little different way, adapting a longstanding Excel function:

```
=DOLLARDE(A1,60)
```

Since the minutes portion is being expressed as a value with a denominator of 60, you can use the `DOLLARDE` function to convert it to a decimal with a denominator of 100.

And to reverse the process, converting the fractional time back to hours.minutes, use:

```
=DOLLARFR(A1,60)
```

Comment: @pnuts Yes, the `DOLLAR` functions have been around a long time, and rarely used. Actually, it has been around a lot longer than 2007.  I just dug out a hard-copy (from back in the day when those came with the software) printing (©1992) of my Excel Function Reference from Excel 4.0, and it includes those functions.

Comment: this is an awesome answer, had never seen those functions before. I think this answer is better than mine, i would down vote mine if i could so this would be at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=INT(A1)+100*MOD(A1,1)/60
```

This should not care about the decimal delimiter (locale insensitive) and leave you with a number rather than text.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with custom format, but if the value is of Date/Time format then you can just multiply it by 24 and change the format to General or Number

```
= A1 * 24
```

Date and Time in Excel are stored as number of days, so `4:45:00 AM` is stored as `0.197916667`

If you enter `0` in a cell and change its format to Date/Time, it will show something like
     `Saturday, January 00, 1900 12:00:00 AM`

Answer (score 0):

This function can be used to convert minute only when data is recorded in 2 digits with correct understanding. Such as 2 minutes is recorded as 0.02.

However general users may record time as text in this fashion instead:

- 0.1 is 1 minute
- 0.2 is 2 minutes.....0.9 is 9 minutes
- 0.10 is 10 minutes
- 0.20 is 20 minutes

this type is unable to use this function.

Compare with the one who knows number formatting as 2 digits will record as
0.01 0.02 ....0.59 that can use this function correctly.

I do not recommend this function to convert time except data is recorded as later sample only.